# Stacking Photos Process

Tags: image-stacking

How do I take multiple photos of an open area that has moving people in it and eliminate them through a photo stacking process?

Thanks

Comment: The answer to the duplicate question should solve the issue as per the letter of your question.

However, you may find that artistically, removing people using the stacking method may not be the best choice.

Using a ND filter and long shutter may be another option, depending on setting.

e.g. image stack to remove people from Horseshoe Bend may be a good choice; image stack to remove people from a man-made landmark may look eerie.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's better to use an ND filter and one or more long exposure time shots. Then blending/stack them. Even in this case there might still be some stationary people.